# JSDoc globalThis & Window object extend

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, window, jsdoc

I'm battling with JSDoc, trying to make it work with new properties on the window object.

I've tried both of the @typedef on the Window & globalThis solutions you see in the snippet, without any luck :(

I have the following code in **JS**

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Routes
 * @property {string} root - Root URL
 * @property {string} product - Product URL
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ThemeObject
 * @property {Routes} routes - All Shopify routes
 */

/**
 * The global `theme` object.
 * @typedef {Window & { theme: ThemeObject }}
 */

/**
 * The global `Window` object.
 * @typedef {globalThis & { theme: ThemeObject }} Window
 */

window.emitter = new Emitter();
window.theme.routes.root;
```

But keeps getting the error in VS Code:

```
Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
```